# TRANSF0ORMAR LISTS EM DICTS UTILIZANDO LIST COMPREHENSIONS

Tags: python

A partir da lista: linguagens = ['python', 'javascript', 'java', 'php', 'c', 'julia'], utilize Dict Comprehension para construir o dicionário abaixo.
DICA: Observe que o valor associado a cada chave corresponde ao tamanho de cada string.
{'python': 6, 'javascript': 10, 'java': 4, 'php': 3, 'c': 1, 'julia': 5}

Consegui fazer de forma 'comum', porém não consegui utilizando a técnica pedida no exercício.

```py
linguagens = ['python', 'javascript', 'java', 'php', 'c', 'julia']
lista_valor = []
for i in range(len(linguagens)):
    lista_valor.append(len(linguagens[i]))
dicionario = dict(zip(linguagens, lista_valor))
print(dicionario)
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema recomdo você a ler este artigo sobre dicionários do python:

https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/dict-comprehensions-no-python

Solução para o problema:

```
linguagens = ['python', 'javascript', 'java', 'php', 'c', 'julia']
dicionario = {l: len(l) for l in linguagens}
print(dicionario)
```